# vim expand contract functions

Tags: vim, plugins

I have a lot of unnecessary code between 2 functions like this:

```
function_a()
function_irrelevant1()
function_irrelevant2()
...
function_irrelevant15()
function_b()
```

I want to contract function_irrelevant1() to function_irrelevant15(), something similar to what I can do with IDE like eclipse.

```
function_a()
+ function_irrelevant1()
+ function_irrelevant2()
...
+ function_irrelevant15()
function_b()
```

When required, I want to be able to expand the irrelevant functions, otherwise keep them contracted (inline).

Is there a plugin/utility that can help me do this in vim?

Comment: That's called "folding", just like in eclipse, and it's a built-in feature. See `:help folding`.

Answer (score 1):

As romainl said, you're are looking for how to *"fold"* your lines.

Where it becomes complex with vim is that you have several methods and you have to choose one:

- either folding is automated and based on indentation, syntax, or a more advanced (or not) plugin
- or your code is parasited with folding marks like {{{1, {{{5, etc.
- or folding is manual.

From what you described, it will be difficult for vim to combine an automated folding method (because I suspect that you'll also want to fold functions, classes, control statements) with the folding of things you want folded, but that the editor has no way to detect as "deserves to be folded".

I'm afraid you'll need to

- either use folding markers (not a very good solution),
- or to write a fold-plugin that does what you want. Alas this is not a simple task. (You'll find an [example here](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C) for C like languages, for the moment it doesn't handle `do...while`, nor embedded `#if`, and it'll always have an issue to adapt itself on code being modified while folding is active.)
- or to inject a way to detect your irrelevant functions into the vim syntax plugin of the language you use -- that may be the best choice you have, not a trivial one, but one that'll may give the best results.